# How to enable jQuery, javascript, CSS files compression

Tags: apache, .htaccess, windows-server

It is my first time I want to enable jQuery, Javascript and CSS files compression

but I don't exactly know where to start I searched the net but there was not a detailed 
example that I could implement that in my project.
Please Help me that how can I enable jQuery, Javascript and CSS files compressions?

1-In windows servers?

2-In Appache Servers?

also can I enable it through .htaccess files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following:

http://www.jsmini.com/

Google released Closure Compiler which seems to be generating the smallest files:
https://code.google.com/p/closure-compiler/

or 
http://yuilibrary.com/download/#yuicompressor

Answer (score -1):

Use Yahoo compressor here is the link: http://yui.github.io/yuicompressor/
for compressing your web pages javascript or jQuery files

or use this JASOB here is the link: http://www.jasob.com/

Comment: I know this but what about compressing the jQuery javascript and css from the server with htaccess